# ReSharper gives an "@" prefix to a variable name in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, resharper

When using ReSharper it automatically adds an `@`, why?

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;
    var normalizedString = input.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var value in normalizedString.Select(value => 
        new {value, unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(value)})
            .Where(@t => @t.unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            .Select(@t => @t.value)) stringBuilder.Append(value);
    return (stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC));
}
```

Comment: I've wondered why too. I'm guessing a convention to help readability, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Using `string.Concat`, you could do away with both the `StringBuilder` and the loop.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The @ symbol allows you to use a reserved keyword for a variable name. Such as `@class`. I'd assume Resharper does this to be safe.

In this case, it is not needed and it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Safe...probably, but that smells of laziness at r# hq, which isn't something I normally associate with r#.

Comment: I noticed that R# sometimes adds `@` before `group`, even in cases where it's not necessary. `group` is a contextual keyword, so the `@` is sometimes necessary, but R# doesn't seem to recognize those cases and just puts the `@` there always.

Comment: @svick: I'm not sure if it *should* recognize those cases.  Putting in an `@` symbol is a nice way of preventing future maintainers from confusing it with the (invalid) contextual keyword.

Comment: It is important to highlight that `@` will not be included in the variable name, means `@group` can still be accessed using `group`

Answer (score 22):

You would have to ask the resharper implementers to be certain, but I can make an educated guess. They are probably *future proofing*.

In the time since C# 1.0 shipped the compiler team has added 21 new *contextual keywords* to C#; the compiler treats these as keywords when they appear in certain locations, and as ordinary identifiers otherwise. `yield`, for example, is only a keyword when it appears before `return`.

When the resharper tool generates code for you, they do not know whether that code is going to be compiled in some hypothetical C# 6 that uses `t` as a contextual keyword in some context. So they "future proof" the design by pre-emptively calling out "this identifier is not a contextual keyword" by putting the `@` on front of it.

Incidentally, this is precisely why it is legal for *any* identifier to be prefixed with `@`.

More information here:

http://ericlippert.com/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords/

Answer (score 4):

Just some context, in ReSharper 5 there was a bug where this:

```
groups.Select(group => ...)
```

would be turned into this

```
from group in groups ...
```

Now, group is a Keyword in LINQ Query Syntax, so R#5's refactoring actually broke the code. In R#6 this was apparently fixed using @ for identifiers.

Comment: Thanks! I've been confused my whole time why resharper is only adding the @ in front of my Group-variable. Now it makes sense to me!

Answer (score 2):

The at-sign (@) escapes the names. E.g. if you want to use `if` as variable name you can write

```
int @if;
```

`if` alone would not work, since `if` is a c# keyword.

The `@` in front of `t` is useless here. Probably the person who wrote that is using his private naming conventions and uses it to denote lambda parameters.

(OK, I see, it was Resharper, not a person, however it could have been).

Answer (score 2):

I've only seen `@` used in this one refactoring: Convert LINQ to Method Chain. In this case, ReSharper is creating a number of lambda variables (possibly a *large* number, depending on the complexity of the lambda expression being converted).

One guess as to the reason is that they might have deliberately used something ugly in the hopes that you'll replace them with meaningful names. There aren't really many hints that ReSharper could use to guess at a meaningful name, so it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

To prefix generated things by @ is a usual behaviour in other generators too.
I saw it at least in a web service proxy generated by wsdl.exe. The WSDL named a property *protected* and the wsdl.exe generated a property with name *@protected*. So there is no conflict with C# keyword *protected*.
But I don't know why *t* is prefixed in your case. Is there a static member in your class which has the name *t*?