# What does '@' in a Lambda expression mean

Tags: c#, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does placing a @ in front of a C# variable name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254669/what-does-placing-a-in-front-of-a-c-sharp-variable-name-do)

I am trying to learn C# lambda expressions. As I search for examples I am seeing the below code

```
Where(@t => string.Compare(@t.Code, argument.Code, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
```

I am wondering what does the '@' symbole before the t mean?

Comment: same as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254669/what-does-placing-a-in-front-of-a-c-sharp-variable-name-do : its just a way to name variables.

Comment: In other words - not needed and confusing, in this case.

Comment: It's an odd choice though, because as far as I know, 't' isn't a keyword in any context...

Comment: @Tharwen - It seems Resharper does that sometimes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304544/resharper-gives-an-prefix-to-a-variable-name-in-a-lambda-expression

Comment: It's just a way to allow declaring reserved keywords as vars.

    void Foo(int @string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing unusual.  You can prefix  varible names with @ as a sort of escape if the varible is a key word.

For example you can also do 'var @class = 5' .  Normally you'd not be able to compile as class is a keyword, but prefixing with @ allows you to use it as a varible.